# Replace NaN with empty list in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to replace some NaN values in my data with an empty list []. However the list is represented as a str and doesn't allow me to properly apply the len() function. is there anyway to replace a NaN value with an actual empty list in pandas?

```
In [28]: d = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [[1,2,3], [1,2], np.NaN, np.NaN], 'y' : [1,2,3,4]})

In [29]: d
Out[29]:
           x  y
0  [1, 2, 3]  1
1     [1, 2]  2
2        NaN  3
3        NaN  4

In [32]: d.x.replace(np.NaN, '[]', inplace=True)

In [33]: d
Out[33]:
           x  y
0  [1, 2, 3]  1
1     [1, 2]  2
2         []  3
3         []  4

In [34]: d.x.apply(len)
Out[34]:
0    3
1    2
2    2
3    2
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This works using `isnull` and `loc` to mask the series:

```
In [90]:
d.loc[d.isnull()] = d.loc[d.isnull()].apply(lambda x: [])
d

Out[90]:
0    [1, 2, 3]
1       [1, 2]
2           []
3           []
dtype: object

In [91]:
d.apply(len)

Out[91]:
0    3
1    2
2    0
3    0
dtype: int64
```

You have to do this using `apply` in order for the list object to not be interpreted as an array to assign back to the df which will try to align the shape back to the original series

**EDIT**

Using your updated sample the following works:

```
In [100]:
d.loc[d['x'].isnull(),['x']] = d.loc[d['x'].isnull(),'x'].apply(lambda x: [])
d

Out[100]:
           x  y
0  [1, 2, 3]  1
1     [1, 2]  2
2         []  3
3         []  4

In [102]:    
d['x'].apply(len)

Out[102]:
0    3
1    2
2    0
3    0
Name: x, dtype: int64
```

Comment: what if we want to extend to the multiple columns of df

Answer (score 12):

To extend the accepted answer, apply calls can be particularly expensive - the same task can be accomplished without it by constructing a numpy array from scratch.

```
isna = df['x'].isna()
df.loc[isna, 'x'] = pd.Series([[]] * isna.sum()).values
```

A quick timing comparison:

```
def empty_assign_1(s):
    s[s.isna()].apply(lambda x: [])

def empty_assign_2(s):
    [[]] * s.isna().sum()

series = pd.Series(np.random.choice([1, 2, np.nan], 1000000))

%timeit empty_assign_1(series)
>>> 61 ms ± 964 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit empty_assign_2(series)
>>> 2.17 ms ± 70.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Nearly 10 times faster!

EDIT:
Fixed a bug pointed out by @valentin

You have to be somewhat careful with data types when performing assignment in this case. In the example above, the test series is float, however, adding `[]` elements coerces the entire series to object. Pandas will handle that for you if you do something like

```
idx = series.isna()
series[isna] = series[isna].apply(lambda x: [])
```

Because the output of apply is itself a series. You can test live performance with assignment overhead like so (I've added a string value so the series with be an object, you could instead use a number as the replacement value rather than an empty list to avoid coercion).

```
def empty_assign_1(s):
    idx = s.isna()
    s[idx] = s[idx].apply(lambda x: [])

def empty_assign_2(s):
    idx = s.isna()
    s.loc[idx] = [[]] * idx.sum()

series = pd.Series(np.random.choice([1, 2, np.nan, '2'], 1000000))

%timeit empty_assign_1(series.copy())
>>> 45.1 ms ± 386 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit empty_assign_2(series.copy())
>>> 24 ms ± 393 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

About 4 ms of that is related to the copy, 10x to 2x, still pretty great.

Comment: This answer is misleading since the implementation of the first function `empty_assign_1()` seems incorrect. It applies the lambda function on *every* element in the series instead of only on those where the value is actually NaN. It should be `s[s.isna()].apply(...)`. Performing the timing comparison after this fix actually reverses the results so that the first function becomes faster.

Comment: Hah! You actually did catch an error, I seem to have forgotten that `isna` is not the reciprocal of `dropna`. That being said, the original post is still correct. The reason you're observing a reversal is because of the unnecessary constructor call to pd.Series (which is also quite slow). Just use `[[]]*s.isna().sum()` and you'll be back in business. The context of this specific question is complicated by replacing nans with a list because of the way pandas interprets list inputs so you'll need to  create `series` with `dtype='object'` and `.loc` for assignment (or replace with a non list).

Answer (score 9):

You can also use a list comprehension for this:

```
d['x'] = [ [] if x is np.NaN else x for x in d['x'] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'column1': [[1, 2], [2, 3], np.nan, [4, 5], np.nan],
        'column2': [np.nan, "Hi", "Hello", np.nan, "H"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def replace_none_with_empty_list(x):
    if x is np.nan:
        return []
    else:
        return x

df = df.applymap(replace_none_with_empty_list)

print(df)
```

wherever NaN is there, this will remove with empty array.else retuns the same value

```
 column1 column2
0  [1, 2]      []
1  [2, 3]      Hi
2      []   Hello
3  [4, 5]      []
4      []       H
```