# How to concatenate two columns containing list (series) in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy, concatenation

I'd like to concatenate two columns in pandas. Each column consists of a list of floating points of 1x4 elements. I'd like to merge two columns such that the output is a vector of 1x8. The below shows a snippet of the dataframe

```
ue,bs
"[1.27932459e-01 7.83234197e-02 3.24789420e-02 4.34971932e-01]","[2.97806183e-01 2.32453145e-01 3.10236304e-01 1.69975788e-02]"
"[0.05627587 0.4113416  0.02160842 0.20420576]","[1.64862491e-01 1.35556330e-01 2.59050065e-02 1.42498115e-02]"
```

To concatenate two columns, I do the following:

```
df['ue_bs'] = zip(df_join['ue'], df_join['bs'])
```

With this, I get a new column 'ue_bs' which contains the following for the first row of `df['ue_bs']`:

```
(array([1.27932459e-01, 7.83234197e-02, 3.24789420e-02, 4.34971932e-01]),
 array([2.97806183e-01, 2.32453145e-01, 3.10236304e-01, 1.69975788e-02]))
```

However, they are still two arrays. In order to merge them, I did it as follows:

```
a = df['ue_bs'][0]
np.concatenate((a[0], a[1]), axis=0)
```

Then, I got

```
array([1.27932459e-01, 7.83234197e-02, 3.24789420e-02, 4.34971932e-01,
   2.97806183e-01, 2.32453145e-01, 3.10236304e-01, 1.69975788e-02])
```

I am wondering is there a neat way of doing this in single line of code, instead of having to loop through `df['ue_bs']` and perform `np.concatenate()`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To concatinate two lists in python, the easiest way is to use `+`. The same is true when concating columns in pandas. You can simply do:

```
df['ue_bs'] = df['ue'] + df['bs']
```

---

If the column type is numpy arrays you can first convert them into normal python lists before the concatination:

```
df['ue_bs'] = df['ue'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()) + df['bs'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

Comment: This works but if other column contains NaN values then, the concatenation results in NaN. Do you have an alternative for this solution?

Comment: @Dagad: An easy solution would be to first replace any NaN values with an empty list, see e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199193/how-to-fill-dataframe-nan-values-with-empty-list-in-pandas

Comment: Okay, will try that and let you know. Also any alternative for avoiding duplicate values?

Comment: @Dagad: You could convert to a set (and back again if you want a list): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53596283/how-to-remove-duplicate-from-a-list-of-a-column-in-a-dataframe-in-python

Comment: I request you to please check my question, I mentioned all issues clearly,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617623/join-2-columns-with-list-values-in-pandas

Answer (score 3):

Create 2d numpy array and then [`numpy.hstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
a = np.array(df[['ue','bs']].values.tolist())
df['ue_bs'] = np.hstack((a[:, 0], a[:, 1])).tolist()

print (df.loc[0, 'ue_bs'])
[0.127932459, 0.0783234197, 0.032478942, 0.434971932, 
 0.297806183, 0.232453145, 0.310236304, 0.0169975788]
```

Comment: How to concatenate list type column row wise in pandas? For example row 1 contains a column with value like row 1=  `1  a  [a,b,c] ` row 2 = `1  b  [a,d]`  result = `1  b  [a,b,c,d]`

Comment: @AlwaysSunny - There are 3 column? And thitd column contain list?

Comment: @AlwaysSunny - So need remove `a`, because exist in `[a,b,c]` ?

Comment: This is my issue, please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738328/pandas-merge-list-with-same-id-row-wise

Comment: @jezrael can you help here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72832711/insert-values-to-a-pandas-column-containing-list-alternatively-from-other-column