# How to remove duplicate from a list of a column in a dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe:

```
id      rev     names
34e     A      su,ra,ve,ra,de,ra
45e     R      ra,su,su,ve,de
55e     G      su,ra,de
41e     M      su,de,mu,er,su
```

Now I need to delete the duplicates, the output should be as below:

```
id      rev     names
34e     A      su,ra,ve,de
45e     R      ra,su,ve,de
55e     G      su,ra,de
41e     M      su,de,mu,er
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Is names a string or a list?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If column contains strings first `split`, convert to `set`s and `join`:

```
df['names'] = df['names'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(set(x.split(','))))
```

If column contains lists converting to `set` and `list` is necessary:

```
df['names'] = df['names'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

If order is important use [`pandas.unique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.unique.html):

```
df['names'] = df['names'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(pd.unique(x.split(','))))

df['names'] = df['names'].apply(lambda x: list(pd.unique(x)))
```

Comment: Maybe the order is matter the pd.unique looks good enough for this type of question :-)

Answer (score 2):

Using `split` follow with `sorted` + `set` , then `join` it back to string

```
df.names.str.split(',').map(lambda x : ','.join(sorted(set(x),key=x.index)))
Out[763]: 
0    su,ra,ve,de
1    ra,su,ve,de
2       su,ra,de
3    su,de,mu,er
Name: names, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming names is of type string:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['34e', 'A', 'su,ra,ve,ra,de,ra'],
        ['45e', 'R', 'ra,su,su,ve,de'],
        ['55e', 'G', 'su,ra,de'],
        ['41e', 'M', 'su,de,mu,er,su']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'rev', 'names'])

df['names'] = [','.join(set(name.split(','))) for name in df.names]
print(df)
```

Or if of type list:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['34e', 'A', ['su', 'ra', 've', 'ra', 'de', 'ra']],
        ['45e', 'R', ['ra', 'su', 'su', 've', 'de']],
        ['55e', 'G', ['su', 'ra', 'de']],
        ['41e', 'M', ['su', 'de', 'mu', 'er', 'su']]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['id', 'rev', 'names'])

df['names'] = [list(set(name)) for name in df.names]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
    id rev             names
0  34e   A  [su, ra, ve, de]
1  45e   R  [su, ra, ve, de]
2  55e   G      [su, ra, de]
3  41e   M  [su, er, mu, de]
```