# Pandas merge list with same id row wise

Tags: python, pandas

How to concatenate list type column row wise in pandas? For example see below-

Before,

```
1  a  [a,b,c]  
1  b  [a,d]
```

After,

```
1  b  [a,b,c,d]
```

I did column wise list concatenating like below,

```
df['all_poi'] = df['poi_part1'] + df['poi_part2']
```

**Current Output**

```
location_id  city            all_poi
6265981     Port Severn     [Mount St. Louis Moonstone , Horseshoe Valley , Lake Muskoka]
6265981     Port Severn     [Mount St. Louis Moonstone ,  Little Lake Park , Bamboo Spa , Lake Huron]
```

**Expected Output**

```
location_id    city             all_poi
6265981     Port Severn     [Mount St. Louis Moonstone , Horseshoe Valley , Lake Muskoka, Little Lake Park , Bamboo Spa , Lake Huron]
```

Check the all_poi value it merges the value based on **location_id**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create sets in custom function in [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
f = lambda x: list(set(z for y in x for z in y))
df = df.groupby(['location_id', 'city'])['all_poi'].agg(f).reset_index()
print (df)
  location_id    city                                            all_poi
0        Port  Severn  [Bamboo Spa, Mount St.Louis Moonstone, Lake Hu...
```

If order and performance is important use `dict` for remove duplicates:

```
f = lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys([z for y in x for z in y]).keys())
```

Another idea is use `unique`:

```
f = lambda x: pd.unique([z for y in x for z in y]).tolist()
```

EDIT:

If there is multiple columns and need first values per groups:

```
df.groupby('location_id').agg({'city': 'first', 'all_poi': f}).reset_index()
```

If need some another aggregations method like `sum`, `mean`, `join`:

```
df.groupby('location_id').agg({'city': 'first', 
                               'all_poi': f, 
                               'cols1':'sum', 
                               'vals': ','.join, 
                               'vals1': lambda x: list(x)}).reset_index()
```

Comment: it works, but I want to group by only location id and get all the other column of my dataframe

Comment: @AlwaysSunny - Do you need first values per groups for another columns?

Comment: this is how I did at last `f = lambda x: list(set(z for y in x for z in y))
mapped_other = mapped_other.groupby(['location_id', 'city','state','country_code'])['all_poi'].agg(f).reset_index()`

Comment: is it ok sir? @jezrael

Comment: @Always Sunny, Yes, it is Ok.

Comment: Your are a star and an inspiration for me as always.Really appreciated sir :) keep doing your awesome help

Answer (score 0):

How about simple `sum()`:

```py
res=df.groupby(["location_id"], as_index=False).agg({"city": "last", "all_poi": "sum"})
res["all_poi"]=res["all_poi"].map(set)
```

Outputs:

```py
Before
   location_id  ...                                                                all_poi
0  6265981      ...  [Mount St. Louis Moonstone, Horseshoe Valley, Lake Muskoka]
1  6265981      ...  [Mount St. Louis Moonstone, Little Lake Park, Bamboo Spa, Lake Huron]

After:
   location_id  ...                                                                                                all_poi
0  6265981      ...  {Horseshoe Valley, Lake Muskoka, Lake Huron, Bamboo Spa, Little Lake Park, Mount St. Louis Moonstone}
```

Comment: Don't use sum to concatenate lists. It looks fancy but it's quadratic and should be considered bad practice. Also OP need remove duplicates.

Comment: What do you mean by `quadratic`? I'm not sure I understand, why is it bad practice, you certainly would do eg. `[1,2,3]+['a', 'b']` to concatenate lists, right?

Comment: For aggregation is used flatten lists, `sum` is worse method here for performnace (but looks cool ;))

Comment: Thanks, I will read through these, didn't think `lambda` can be faster than simple sum - but I can see it's a deeper topic :)

Comment: It depends, if lists then yes, else not.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the below answers are more compact, but you can apply `sum` with the groupby to combine the lists. Then create a set to get rid of the duplicates, and convert from `set` to `list`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['1' ,'New York', ['a','b','c']], ['1', 'New York', ['a','d']]],
                   columns = ['location_id', 'city','all_poi'])

df.groupby(('location_id'))['all_poi'].apply(sum).apply(set).apply(list)
```

Comment: That's literally my answer mate ☺️