# How to combine two columns containing np.arrays to one column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am reading in a CSV file that contains arrays in the columns. I would like to concatenate the lists in the columns together into a new column containing just one list as I have to do some transformations with it.

```
d = {'col1': [[1,2], [1,2],[1,2]], 'col2': [[1,2], [], [1,2,4,5,6,7]]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

```
    col1    col2
0   [1, 2]  [1, 2]
1   [1, 2]  []
2   [1, 2]  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

In a first step I convert them to numerical arrays.

```
df["col1"] = df['col1'].apply(lambda x : np.fromstring(str(x).replace('[','').replace(']',''), sep=',').astype(int))
df["col2"] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x : np.fromstring(str(x).replace('[','').replace(']',''), sep=',').astype(int))
```

In a second step I want to combine them in one column.

```
    col1    col2                col3
0   [1, 2]  [1, 2]              [1, 2, 1, 2]
1   [1, 2]  []                  [1, 2]  
2   [2, 3]  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]  [2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

but I always end up with

```
    col1    col2                col3
0   [1, 2]  [1, 2]              [[1, 2], [1, 2]]
1   [1, 2]  []                  [[1, 2], []]  
2   [2, 3]  [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]  [[2, 3], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: `df['col3'] = df['col1'].agg(np.ndarray.tolist) + df['col2'].agg(np.ndarray.tolist)` although it's probably more efficient if your column is already a list to just add then convert to an array `df['col3'] = (df['col1'] + df['col2']).agg(np.array)`

Comment: `df` as originally created has lists in the columns.  As the duplicate shows, `df['col1']+df['col2']` works.  Converting to arrays makes that impossible.  How are you doing the "always ends up" step?  But when loading from the `csv` are you really getting lists?  Or are they strings that look like lists?  `pandas` display doesn't distinguish those 3 cases.

Comment: When I read the csv file it is a string, that's why I apply the lambda function. 
I tried df['col1']+df['col2'], I tried .apply(''.join,1)
.apply(lambda x: x.to_numpy(), 1) and several different functions and nothing resulted in the preferred outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you can combine multiple lists together using addition (`+`) in Python (e.g. `[1,2] + [3,4] == [1,2,3,4]`), you can do the exact same thing using Pandas Series.

Since the items are numpy arrays, which define addition on each other differently (i.e, adding each individual value from each array together into a new array of the same shape, rather than concatenation as Python `list`s do), you'll need to convert the numpy arrays to Python lists first, using `.apply(list)`:

```py
df['col3'] = df['col1'].apply(list) + df['col2'].apply(list)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! It works.
Can you share a link to the duplicate, I though I reviewed all relevant questions before asking this question.

Comment: If you look at the top of this question, you should see a blue box containing a link to the question. Anyway, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51870724/how-to-concatenate-two-columns-containing-list-series-in-pandas