# Join 2 columns with list values in pandas(Avoiding duplicates and NaN)

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have pandas dataframe as follows,

```
loc_1                               loc_2                             

[mumbai, gujarat, sri lanka]        [chennai, UP]
[Goa, telangana]                    [Kashmir, Goa, Rajkot]
NaN                                 [Bihar, Orissa]
```

I want to create a new column that is a combination of both the above columns,
I did search other similar questions but the issue I am facing is that,

When I do,

```
data['locations'] = data['loc_1'] + data['loc_2']

Output
--------
loc_1                               loc_2                       locations

[mumbai, gujarat, sri lanka]        [chennai, UP]                [mumbai, gujarat, sri lanka,chennai, UP]   
[Goa, telangana]                    [Kashmir, Goa, Rajkot]       [Goa, telangana,Kashmir, Goa, Rajkot]
NaN                                 [Bihar, Orissa]              NaN
```

### Issue

As you can see above, there are duplicate values as well as NaN values formed.
How to avoid them?

### Remember

The original dataset contains values in list, str and NaN format.

### Dataset:

```
loc = pd.DataFrame({
'loc_1': [['mumbai', 'gujarat', 'sri lanka'],['Goa', 'telangana'],np.nan],
'loc_2':[['chennai','UP'],['kashmir','goa','rajkot'],['bihar','orissa']],
'loc_3':['Chennai','Bangalore','Vizag']

})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First join values with replace `NaN`s (floats) to empty lists:

```
data['locations'] = data['loc_1'].apply(lambda x: [] if isinstance(x, float) else x) + data['loc_2']
```

And then remove duplicates with same order like original by converting to dictionaries by `dict.fromkeys`:

```
data['locations'] = data['locations'].apply(lambda x: list(dict.fromkeys(x)))
```

If the order is not important you can use a set:

```
data['locations'] = data['locations'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x)))
```

Comment: This unexplained code doesn't address the duplicate issue.

Comment: @wwnde - why not apply?

Comment: @wwnde - `apply` for `Series` is really fast, so I decide use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `loc.fillna("", inplace=True)`, then additions containing empty values should not result in NaNs anymore.

To filter duplicates from a column containing lists, use:

```
loc['locations'] = loc['locations'].apply(lambda locs: list(set(locs)))
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehension can be quite quick. Lets try

```
   data['location']=[list(set([] if isinstance(x, float) else x).union(set(y))) for x,y in zip (data['loc_1'],data['loc_2'])]

 

      loc_1                     loc_2      loc_3  \
0  [mumbai, gujarat, sri lanka]  [chennai, UP, sri lanka]    Chennai   
1              [Goa, telangana]    [kashmir, goa, rajkot]  Bangalore   
2                           NaN           [bihar, orissa]      Vizag   

                                    location  
0  [chennai, UP, gujarat, mumbai, sri lanka]  
1     [telangana, rajkot, goa, kashmir, Goa]  
2                            [bihar, orissa]
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : replace all Nans with empty list so it takes care of NAN

```
    #Function to remove Nans
    def isnan(x):
       if isinstance(x, (int,  float, complex)) and math.isnan(x):
          return True

    # Apply to your data
    loc1 = loc.apply(lambda x:x.apply(lambda x:[] if isnan(x) else x))
```

2. Step 2: After concatenating take the set, to remove duplicates

   ```
    loc1['location'] = (loc1['loc_1']  + loc1['loc_2']).apply(set)
   ```

If you want the final results not to be set please convert to list