# Pandas: Convert nan in a row to an empty array

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframes are like below

df1

```
id   c1
1    abc
2    def
3    ghi
```

df2

```
id   set1
1    [123,456]
2    [789]
```

When I join df1 and df2  `(final_data = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left'))`. It gives me

final_df

```
id   c1   set1
1    abc  [123,456]
2    def  [789]
3    ghi  NaN
```

I'm using below code to replace NaN with empty array []

```
for row in final_df.loc[final_df.set1.isnull(), 'set1'].index:
        final_df.at[row, 'set1'] = []
```

The issue is if df2 is empty dataframe. It is giving

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

PS: I'm using pandas 0.23.4 version

Comment: Pandas isn't really designed to work with collections in a single cell. `fillna()` is not allowing me to set an empty array, I fear whatever solution exists will be hacky. You should note that you get none of the nice vectorized features of numpy/pandas with this structure.

Comment: Possible duplicate ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199193/how-to-fill-dataframe-nan-values-with-empty-list-in-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is not designed to be used with series of lists. You lose all vectorised functionality and any manipulations on such series involve inefficient, Python-level loops.

One work-around is to define a series of empty lists:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, how='left')

empty = pd.Series([[] for _ in range(len(df.index))], index=df.index)
res['set1'] = res['set1'].fillna(empty)

print(res)

   id   c1        set1
0   1  abc  [123, 456]
1   2  def       [789]
2   3  ghi          []
```

A better idea at this point, if viable, is to split your lists into separate series:

```
res = res.join(pd.DataFrame(res.pop('set1').values.tolist()))

print(res)

   id   c1      0      1
0   1  abc  123.0  456.0
1   2  def  789.0    NaN
2   3  ghi    NaN    NaN
```

Comment: I'm going to convert that dataframe to a JSON.
So i'll get it like 
 [{
  "id" : 1,
  "c1" : "abc",
  "set1" : [123,456]
 },{
  "id" : 3,
  "c1" : "ghi",
  "set1" : []
 }]

Comment: @HemanthS.Vaddi, OK, that's a different new question. You should [ask a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) as to the most efficient way to construct your json.

Answer (score 0):

This is is not ideal but will get your work done

```
import pandas as  pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,'abc'],[2,'def'],[3,'ghi']], columns=['id', 'c1'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,[123,456]],[2,[789]]], columns=['id', 'set1'])
df=pd.merge(df1,df2, how='left', on='id')
df['set1'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
df['set1']=df['set1'].apply( lambda x:pd.Series({'set1': [] if x == 0 else x}))
print(df)
```

Comment: This is actually error-prone. You're relying on there being no 0 values. The OP already has mixed types because they have lists and `NaN`. It's not a safe assumption that they didn't also have bare 0's in that column