# Use empty list as fill value for Series.fillna

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I need to change the NaN values the column `'FocusColumn'` to empty lists.

---

I tried to do it like this:

```
df['FocusColumn'].fillna([],inplace=True)
```

But it throws me the following error:

```
337         if validate_scalar_dict_value and isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
338             raise TypeError( 
339                 '"value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but 
340                 f'you passed a "{type(value).__name__}"'
341             )
TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but you passed a "list"
```

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you want to fill this with a list? why don't you set a string value or a float?

Comment: I upvoted this because I did not know that `fillna` does not play nice with lists, but you should really ask yourself why you are putting lists into DataFrames. You are losing most of the speed and convenience of `pandas`.

Comment: Because I export that dataframe as Json, and I need that field to be a list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fill dataframe Nan values with empty list \[\] in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199193/how-to-fill-dataframe-nan-values-with-empty-list-in-pandas)

Comment: I think this question can be reopened since it focuses on filling missing values in a single column/Series, which surprisingly works a little different than filling missing values in a DataFrame (linked dupe).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you can work around this by supplying a dict to `Series.fillna`.

```
>>> df
   FocusColumn
0          NaN
1          1.0
2          NaN
>>> df['FocusColumn'].fillna({i: [] for i in df.index})
0    []
1     1
2    []
Name: FocusColumn, dtype: object
```

Notes:

1. Surprisingly, this only works for [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html).
2. For large Series with few missing values, this might create an unreasonable amount of throwaway empty lists.
3. Tested with `pandas` 1.0.5.

Comment: It is better create it by for loop, `df.iloc[0,0].append([0])` [] here have the same id ~

Comment: It works for Series only because for DataFrame.fillna with dict value works for columns. You can use argument `{i: [] for i in df.columns}` with DataFrames.

Comment: @GregoryShimansky I'm getting `TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but you passed a "list"` when I try `df.fillna({i: [] for i in df.columns})`. `pandas` 1.2.3

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'FocusColumn': [1, 2, 3, 4, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN], 'Column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'Column2': [7, 8, 6, 5, 7, 8, 5, 4]})

df['FocusColumn'] = df['FocusColumn'].apply(lambda x: [] if np.isnan(x) else x)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  FocusColumn  Column1  Column2
0           1        1       7
1           2        2       8
2           3        3       6
3           4        4       5
4          []        5       7
5          []        6       8
6          []        7       5
7          []        8       4
```

Comment: OP does not want to check for the string `'NaN'`, but for `np.nan`. (Which gives `False` when comparing to itself.)

Comment: Agree, it is better to test for `NaN` with a standard method, not `==`.