# Replacing nan values in a Pandas data frame with lists

Tags: python, pandas

How to replace nan or empty strings (e.g. "") with zero if it exists in any column. the values in any column can be a combination of lists and scalar values as follows

```
col1  col2    col3            col4 
nan   Jhon    [nan, 1, 2]    ['k', 'j']
1     nan     [1, 1, 5]       3
2     ""      nan             nan
3     Samy    [1, 1, nan]    ['b', '']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to handle the three cases (empty string, NaN, NaN in list) separately.

For the NaN in list you need to loop over each occurrence and replace the elements one by one.

*NB. `applymap` is slow, so if you know in advance the columns to use you can subset them*

For the empty string, replace them to NaN, then `fillna`.

```
sub = 'X'
(df.applymap(lambda x: [sub if (pd.isna(e) or e=='')
                        else e for e in x]
                       if isinstance(x, list) else x)
   .replace('', float('nan'))
   .fillna(sub)
 )
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2       col3    col4
0    X  Jhon  [X, 1, 2]  [k, j]
1  1.0     X  [1, 1, 5]       3
2  2.0     X          X       X
3  3.0  Samy  [1, 1, X]  [b, X]
```

Used input:

```
from numpy import nan
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: nan, 1: 1.0, 2: 2.0, 3: 3.0},
                   'col2': {0: 'Jhon', 1: nan, 2: '', 3: 'Samy'},
                   'col3': {0: [nan, 1, 2], 1: [1, 1, 5], 2: nan, 3: [1, 1, nan]},
                   'col4': {0: ['k', 'j'], 1: '3', 2: nan, 3: ['b', '']}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and after some research i came up to a solution that works quite well. The solution does require any knowledge about the columns that contains NA a priori. The solution is described briefly in another thread.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33199193/how-to-fill-dataframe-nan-values-with-empty-list-in-pandas/76043985#76043985](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043985/942728)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34244183)

Comment: The solution described in the linked thread does apply very well to solve the question. I just don't want to duplicate the answer unnecessarily.