# How to combine two pandas series that contain lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes representing each row a different author. There is also a column called 'publications' representing the list of publication_ids of that author which min_len = 1.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'publications':[[34499803], [34499125], [34445802, 7092834]]}, index=['0', '4', '2423'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'publications':[[65499803, 56899232], [78999821], [87499234]]}, index=['2234', '543', '345'])
```

**How can I combine them so that the results look like this?**

```
df_sum = pd.DataFrame({'publications':[[65499803, 56899232, 34499803], [78999821, 34499125], [87499234, 34445802, 7092834]]}, index=['0', '4', '2423'])
```

The order of the elements does not matter. I tried using + but I get np.NaN, also [add](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) but it complains about the types (TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list')

Note: I edited the question as I realized the minimal example I provided was not capturing the problem which comes from the indices. As I am combining the two tables I only care about keeping df_1 indices

Comment: `df_1 + df_2` works like a charm, what `add` have you tried? Or maybe your example isn't representative for the problem?

Comment: Your example works...

Comment: I think problem is `NAN`s, need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567218/replace-nan-with-empty-list-in-a-pandas-dataframe) for repalce them to emty lists

Comment: Is length of both DataFrames same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is different index values, so if length is same of both DataFrames add `reset_index(drop=True)`:

```
df = df_1.reset_index(drop=True).add(df_2.reset_index(drop=True))

print (df)
                     publications
0  [34499803, 65499803, 56899232]
1            [34499125, 78999821]
2   [34445802, 7092834, 87499234]
```

If need same index like `df_1` use:

```
df = df_1.add(df_2.set_index(df_1.index))

print (df)
                        publications
0     [34499803, 65499803, 56899232]
4               [34499125, 78999821]
2423   [34445802, 7092834, 87499234]
```

Comment: As my dataset had multiple columns I had to modify a bit the solution to df_1.loc[idx_1, 'publications'] = df_1.loc[idx_1, 'column'].add(df_2.loc[idx_2, 'column'].values)

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to reproduce your problem by adding a singe value as float:

```
>>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'publications':[[34499803], float(34499125), [34445802, 7092834]]})
>>> df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'publications':[[65499803, 56899232], [78999821], [87499234]]})
>>> df_1+df_2
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'list'
```

if this is the case, it can be solved by transforming the single values into lists:

```
>>> df_1["publications"]=df_1["publications"].apply(lambda x: [x] if isinstance(x, float) else x)
>>> df_1+df_2
                     publications
0  [34499803, 65499803, 56899232]
1          [34499125.0, 78999821]
2   [34445802, 7092834, 87499234]
```

Answer (score 0):

well I was guessing that the index number are important

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'publications':[[34499803], [34499125], [34445802, 7092834]]}, index=['0', '4', '2423'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'publications':[[65499803, 56899232], [78999821], [87499234]]}, index=['2234', '543', '345'])
df_1 = df_1.reset_index(drop=False)
df_2 = df_2.reset_index(drop=True)
df_sum = df_1
df_sum.publications = df_1.publications + df_2.publications
df_sum = df_sum.set_index('index')

                         publications
index                                
0      [34499803, 65499803, 56899232]
4                [34499125, 78999821]
2423    [34445802, 7092834, 87499234]
```

this way you keep the index but this also assumes that both df have the same length