# Why cant Pandas replace nan with an array of 0s using masks/replace?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a series like this

```py
s = pd.Series([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],np.nan,[1,2,3],[1,2,3],np.nan])
```

and I simply want the `NaN` to be replaced by `[0,0,0]`.

I have tried

```py
s.fillna([0,0,0]) # TypeError: "value" parameter must be a scalar or dict, but you passed a "list"

s[s.isna()] = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0]] # just replaces the NaN with a single "0". WHY?!

s.fillna("NAN").replace({"NAN":[0,0,0]}) # ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot 
                                          #assign 3 input values to the 2 output values where the mask is true


s.fillna("NAN").replace({"NAN":[[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]}) # TypeError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment
                                                   # requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions
```

I really can't understand, why the two first approaches won't work (maybe I get the first, but the second I cant wrap my head around).

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31567218/replace-nan-with-empty-list-in-a-pandas-dataframe) SO-question and answer, we can do it by

```py
is_na = s.isna()
s.loc[is_na] = s.loc[is_na].apply(lambda x: [0,0,0])
```

but since `apply` often is rather slow I cannot understand, why we can't use `replace` or the slicing as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) indicates that this value cannot be a `list`.

> Value to use to fill holes (e.g. 0), alternately a
> dict/Series/DataFrame of values specifying which value to use for each
> index (for a Series) or column (for a DataFrame). Values not in the
> dict/Series/DataFrame will not be filled. **This value cannot be a list.**

This is probably a limitation of the current implementation, and short of patching the source code you must resort to workarounds (as provided below).

---

However, if you are not planning to work with jagged arrays, what you really want to do is probably replace `pd.Series()` with `pd.DataFrame()`, e.g.:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


s = pd.DataFrame(
        [[1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3],
         [np.nan],
         [1, 2, 3],
         [1, 2, 3],
         [np.nan]],
        dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())  # to mix integers with NaNs


s.fillna(0)
#    0  1  2
# 0  1  2  3
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  0  0  0
# 3  1  2  3
# 4  1  2  3
# 5  0  0  0
```

---

If you do need to use jagged array, you could use any of the proposed workaround from other answers, or you could make one of your attempt work, e.g.:

```py
ii = s.isna()
nn = ii.sum()
s[ii] = pd.Series([[0, 0, 0]] * nn).to_numpy()
# 0    [1, 2, 3]
# 1    [1, 2, 3]
# 2    [0, 0, 0]
# 3    [1, 2, 3]
# 4    [1, 2, 3]
# 5    [0, 0, 0]
# dtype: object
```

which basically uses NumPy masking to fill in the Series. The trick is to generate a compatible object for the assignment that works at the NumPy level.

If there are too many NaNs in the input, it is probably more efficient / faster to work in a similar way but with `s.notna()` instead, e.g.:

```py
import pandas as pd


result = pd.Series([[0, 0, 0]] * len(s))
result[s.notna()] = s[s.notna()]
```

---

Let's try to do some benchmarking, where:

- `replace_nan_isna()` is from above

```py
import pandas as pd


def replace_nan_isna(s, value, inplace=False):
    if not inplace:
        s = s.copy()
    ii = s.isna()
    nn = ii.sum()
    s[ii] = pd.Series([value] * nn).to_numpy()
    return s
```

- `replace_nan_notna()` is also from above

```
import pandas as pd


def replace_nan_notna(s, value, inplace=False):
    if inplace:
        raise ValueError("In-place not supported!")
    result = pd.Series([value] * len(s))
    result[s.notna()] = s[s.notna()]
    return result
```

- `replace_nan_reindex()` is from [@ShubhamSharma's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72257434/5218354)

```py
def replace_nan_reindex(s, value, inplace=False):
    if not inplace:
        s = s.copy()
    s.dropna().reindex(s.index, fill_value=value)
    return s
```

- `replace_nan_fillna()` is from [@jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72257416/5218354)

```py
import pandas as pd


def replace_nan_fillna(s, value, inplace=False):
    if not inplace:
        s = s.copy()
    s.fillna(pd.Series([value] * len(s), index=s.index))
    return s
```

with the following code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def gen_data(n=5, k=2, p=0.7, obj=(1, 2, 3)):
    return pd.Series(([obj] * int(p * n) + [np.nan] * (n - int(p * n))) * k)


funcs = replace_nan_isna, replace_nan_notna, replace_nan_reindex, replace_nan_fillna

# : inspect results
s = gen_data(5, 1)
for func in funcs:
    print(f'{func.__name__:>20s}  {func(s, value)}')
print()

# : generate benchmarks
s = gen_data(100, 1000)
value = (0, 0, 0)
base = funcs[0](s, value)
for func in funcs:
    print(f'{func.__name__:>20s}  {(func(s, value) == base).all()!s:>5}', end='  ')
    %timeit func(s, value)
#     replace_nan_isna   True  100 loops, best of 5: 16.5 ms per loop
#    replace_nan_notna   True  10 loops, best of 5: 46.5 ms per loop
#  replace_nan_reindex   True  100 loops, best of 5: 9.74 ms per loop
#   replace_nan_fillna   True  10 loops, best of 5: 36.4 ms per loop
```

indicating that `reindex()` may be the fastest approach.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas working with list with pain, here is hacky solution:

```
s = s.fillna(pd.Series([[0,0,0]] * len(s), index=s.index))
print (s)
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [1, 2, 3]
2    [0, 0, 0]
3    [1, 2, 3]
4    [1, 2, 3]
5    [0, 0, 0]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

### `Series.reindex`

```
s.dropna().reindex(s.index, fill_value=[0, 0, 0])
```

---

```
0    [1, 2, 3]
1    [1, 2, 3]
2    [0, 0, 0]
3    [1, 2, 3]
4    [1, 2, 3]
5    [0, 0, 0]
dtype: object
```